# I have two questions about dynamic SQL ;please explain why, thank you

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

```
This is first code,no error
L_SQL := 'SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM TABLE A
          WHERE COL1 = ''' || V_1 || '''     -- where col1 = '2021YEAR_REPORT'
          AND COL2 LIKE ''%' || V_2 || '''   -- and col2 like '%202302'
          AND COL3 = ''' || 
          V_4 || '''';

This is second code,error PLS-00103
create or replace noneditionable procedure p1 is
  v1    varchar2(10);
  v_new number(10);
  sql_1 varchar2(200);
begin
  for i in 1..10 loop
    begin
    v1 := to_char( i);
    end;
  end loop;
  sql_1 := 'select count(1) from table_1 a where a.col1 ='|| ''v1''; -- error
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_1
          into v_new;
end;
```

---

Both are dynamic SQL issues, first code is correct, but I'm very confused about the use of ' in it, why there so many ''', When encountering this situation in the future, how should I write code, or read other people's code? For research how to use ', I wrote down the second piece of code and he reported an error, this confuses me, even more, Please help me sort out this knowledge point, I will be very grateful to you

Comment: Just print the statement instead/before execution (using `dbms_output`) and execute it manually from the SQL editor. This way you'll validate the text by yourself and will be able to use editor's syntax highlighting.

Comment: By the way, I recommend using the standard SQL expression for row counting, which is `count(*)`. Counting some arbitrary literal just gives the parser the extra job of changing it to the standard version. Admittedly that takes it about a nanosecond, but why not just use the standard version in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My other answer addressed the question about the single quotes. Now I will address your error.

```
sql_1 := 'select count(1) from table_1 a where a.col1 ='|| ''v1''; -- error
```

The correct syntax would be:

```
sql_1 := 'select count(1) from table_1 a where a.col1 ='''|| v1 ||'''';
```

That places an escaped (doubled) single quote before the v1, and one after.

However, I would advise you not to use string literals and concatenation of variable contents like this at all. In fact, you don't need dynamic SQL at all to do what you're doing. Simply do this:

```
for i in 1..10 loop
  select count(1) into v_new from table_1 a where a.col1 = to_char( i);
end loop;
```

Only if you are dynamically defining an object name, like the table name or a column name, or adding an extra join clause or an extra table dynamically would you need to use dynamic SQL, and you aren't doing any of that. For just plugging in a new predicate, we use normal bind variables.

If you did need to use dynamic SQL for any reason, you can still use bind variables for your predicates, like this:

```
for i in 1..10 loop
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(1) from table_1 a where a.col1 = to_char(:b1)' into v_new USING i;
end loop;
```

This will make your DBA happy with you, as you will avoid filling up the shared pool with unsharable cursors.

Answer (score 0):

The single quote is the string literal terminator in Oracle. Dynamic SQL is defined by a string (the SQL statement as a string literal), and therefore must be enclosed in single quotes. But often there is need to use single quotes for something *inside* the dynamic SQL, and so it must be "escaped" so that it is not interpreted as ending the outer string. In Oracle, we do this by doubling the single quote character. When you see three single quotes, one actually ends or starts the outer string, while the other two represent an escaped character within the string.

There is an alternative, called the Q quoting mechanism. Here's a link to read up on it: [Quoting string literals](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311)